# Not displaying my navbar {% extends 'base.html' %} when I use django {% block content %}

Tags: python, html, css, django

When I use {% extends 'base.html' %} my navbar displays correctly but when I use {% block content %}

## Hello World

{% endblock content %} my navbar disappears and I only see the text "Hello World". I dont really know what to try it appeared to be straight forward but apparently it isn't until you actually know.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}<h1>Hello World</h1>{% endblock content %}
```

My 'base.html' file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
{% block head %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my title goes here</title>
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="navbar custom-navbar">
                    <h1>World Truthers</h1>

                    <div class="col navbar-buttons">
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Contact</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>About</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Returns</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Payment</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Delivery</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Store</b></p></button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your base.html to the one below. What is happening is you are overwriting your content block with whats in your template ("Hello world"). If you want to stick with this, in your child template, put `{{block.super}}` after `{% block content %}`, but the "correct" way would be to change your base.html with the one below.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
{% block head %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my title goes here</title>
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="navbar custom-navbar">
                    <h1>World Truthers</h1>

                    <div class="col navbar-buttons">
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Contact</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>About</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Returns</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Payment</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Delivery</b></p></button>
                        <button class="btn custom-button"><p><b>Store</b></p></button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```